# Sublime Text Regex Replace include index?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm doing a regex replace using Sublime Text 2, and it'd be really helpful if there was a way to add the index of the occurrence or line number to my result.

For example, I have a long list of properties that I am importing from an Excel file, and I grab this information by including the index of that column. So right now I am manually going in and updating the index of the column to assign the data to the correct property.

This is my current find text:

Find: `public (int|string) (.*) \{ get; set; \}\n?`

In theory, how I'd like it to work:

Replace: `case [index]:\n\t\t$2 = data;\n\t\tbreak;`

Sample Input:

```
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@HistoryId", HistoryId));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@Index", Index));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@EditDate", EditDate));
p.Add(new SqlParameter("@Track", Track));
```

Expected Output:

```
case 1:
   HistoryId = data;
   break;
case 2:
   Index = data;
   break;
case 3:
   EditDate = data;
   break;
case 4:
   Track = data;
   break;
```

etc.

Comment: For some context, I add all the columns to a class manually - then via Regex Find/Replace, I create the SqlParameters, SQL Table and Stored Proc.

Comment: sample input and expected output would be better.